# Javascript and React-native: How to properly move part of a component into a new class?

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, javascript-objects

I am currently trying to implement a Map-Component. I want to move out the GPS logic to a different file. However, I am getting an error `[_pGPS2.default.getCurLocation] is not a function`.

My code looks as follows:

```
import { Provider as MobXProvider, observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import { Store } from '../Store.js';

@observer
class pGPS {

  constructor(){
    this.gpsPos.lat = 0;
    this.gpsPos.lng = 0;

    this.watchID = null;
  }

  getCurLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
      var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
      };
      this.setState({
        gpsPosition: initialRegion
      });

    }, (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)), {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 2000,
      maximumAge: 1000
    });
  }

    ...

}

export default new pGPS();
```

In the next file, I call a function like this:

```
import pGPS from './pGPS.js';
...
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MapComponent did mount!");
    pGPS.getCurLocation();
    pGPS.watchCurLocation();
  }
```

How can I properly import methods of a class which I can then call? I am a beginner to JavaScript, so any ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `instance` class, not a `static` one. You need to instantiate it with `let gps = new pGPS()` before calling its methods

```js
class GPS {

  constructor() {
    this.lat = 0;
    this.lng = 0;
  }

  getCurLocation() {
    console.log(this.lat);
  }

}

let gps = new GPS();
gps.getCurLocation();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! :) If I want to create, say a `User object`, how can I successfully do this? As I understand, with the upper example, anytime I call `import {gps} from gpsFile.js` a new object is created. Is it possible to always import the same object to this?

Comment: `import` just brings in the method / uninstantiated objects etc, not the created objects. For that you've got a few options, depends on how you want to access said objects. If it's application wide you can use redux to store application state -> http://www.reactnative.com/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux/. If this answer helped, please choose as the correct answer :)

Comment: So I am using mobx, but it seems like it's not fully clear on what makes stuff global and what not. Could you maybe help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679881/react-native-and-mobx-how-to-create-a-global-store, oh and thanks for the answer :)